# How do i nessus scan to the EC2 server which is behind load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, aws-ec2, web-application-firewall, nessus

I have a EC2 server which is running behind a load balancer. Load balancer URL has been mapped as A record in route53.

Audit team is asking for the public ip address. How do i give them?

ALB URL even if i share , how do we acheive that EC2 server which is under targetgroups gets scanned?

Nessus is the tool being used.

Comment: What are they looking for? Public attack surface?

Comment: All the network env in EC2 to be scanned.
They will be scanning the services installed in server with the ports .

Comment: Then you somehow will have to give them access to this VM - either via VPN, exposing it publically, or giving them a VM in the same net to do the tests from...

Comment: It is a great idea to expose a server publicly just for a scan. /s